# Example of expression where the precedence of AND (&&) over OR (||) matters?

Tags: javascript, operators, operator-precedence

In all of the JavaScript operator precedence charts I can find (like [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) and [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/z3ks45k7(v=vs.94).aspx)), the logical AND (`&&`) has *slightly* higher precedence to the logical OR (`||`).

I can't seem to figure out an expression where the result is different than it would be if they had the same precedence. I figure there must be some way for it to matter or they'd be listed as having the same precedence if it didn't.

For example:

```
0 || 2 && 0 || 3
```

is `3`, but it doesn't matter how I slice that up, it's always going to be `3`:

```
(0 || 2) && 0 || 3

0 || (2 && 0) || 3

(0 || 2 && 0) || 3

0 || 2 && (0 || 3)

0 || (2 && 0 || 3)
```

If I make that first `0` something else (like `4`), the result is always `4` because the first `||` doesn't even look at the right-hand side. If I swap the `0` and `3` in the last `||` around, the result remains `3`.

The closest I've come is

```
0 || false && "" || NaN
```

...which is `NaN`, whereas

```
0 || false && ("" || NaN)
```

...is `false`, but I think that's explained purely by the left-to-right semantics, not by `&&` being higher precedence.

I must just be missing it, for what expression does it matter that `&&` has a higher precedence than `||`?

Comment: just making a guess: as a fallback maybe?

Comment: `true || false && false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they had the same precedence and were left-associative, then e.g. the expression

```
1 || 0 && 2
```

would be

```
((1 || 0) && 2) // evaluates to 2
```

instead of the

```
(1 || (0 && 2)) // evaluates to 1
```

that we get from the "usual" precedence rules.

---

For your structure `… || … && … || …` (which would be `(((… || …) && …) || …)` instead of normal `((… || (… && …)) || …)`), you'd get different results for values like `0 0 1 0`.

---

> Why does the logical AND have slightly higher precedence to the logical OR?

So that the canonical form of boolean expressions, the [disjunctive normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form), does not need any parenthesis.

Answer (score 5):

```
true || false && false
```

is `true`

```
(true || false) && false
```

is `false`

```
true || (false && false)
```

is `true`

Comment: It's also easy to see a difference if you use objects instead of booleans.  For instance, `{a:1} || {b:2} && {c:3} || {d:4} && {e:5}` gives `{a:1}`, while `({a:1} || {b:2}) && ({c:3} || {d:4}) && {e:5}` gives `{e:5}`.

Comment: @aroth: Except that all objects are truthy. But using (say) `1 || 0 && ""` would make this clearer, as it's `1` but `(1 || 0) && ""` is `""`.

Comment: Thank you! This had been bugging me for ages, I couldn't seem to find an example where this happened

Answer (score 1):

Example:

`1 || 0 && 0` -> `(1 || 0) && 0` -> `(1) && 0` -> **0**
`1 || 0 && 0` -> `1 || (0 && 0)` -> `1 || (0)` -> **1**

Answer (score 0):

It's fun to answer the question algebraically:

(x | y) & z   ≠   x | (y & z)

Expanding out the first bracketed term:

(x & z) | (y & z)   ≠   x | (y & z)

Since y & z is equal to itself, the difference must come from:

x & z   ≠   x

which is false if x = false so x = true, giving

true & z   ≠   true

or

z   ≠   true

So z = false.

Substituting x = true, z = false back into the original expression:

(true | y) & false   ≠   true | (y & false)

So either value of y demonstrates the difference.